# REST put request to update geojson document in MongoDB using Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I've been following a Youtube tutorial on creating a RESTful API (I'm just getting to grips with this field). The tutorial is about books, but I wanted to extend it to support geoJSON as that's my end goal.

I have no problem updating fields if they're at the root of the document such as:

```
first_name: object.first_name,
```

What I don't understand is how to update fields that exist as part of a subdocument:

```
geometry: { coordinates: [] },
```

I've tried using geometry.coordinates and the above structure, nether of which have worked.

Here's what I have:

Update Function from object model

```
// Update Object
module.exports.updateObject = function(id, object, options, callback)
{
    var query = { _id: id};
    var update = {
            geometry:
            {
                type: object.geometry.type,
                coordinates: object.geometry.coordinates
            },
            properties:
            {
                icon: object.properties.icon,
                title: object.properties.title,
                description: object.properties.description
            }

    }
    User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
};
```

app put function from app.js

```
app.put('/api/objects/:_id', function(req, res)
{
    var id = req.params._id
    var object = req.body;

    Object.updateObject(id, object, {}, function(err, object)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        } 

        res.json(object);
    });
});
```

PUT Request from web

```
{
    "geometry": 
    {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-90.5299938027191,                  24.42859997065679]
    },
    "properties":
    {
        "icon": "bar-15",
        "title": "Bar",
        "description": "A Bar"
     }    
}
```

HTTP Response

```
200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2017 23:24:58 GMT
ETag: W/"4-N6YlnMDB2uKZp4Zkid/wvQ"
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
null
```

Example mongo object

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("58815cd0110dcc3b1e51d411"),
   "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
       -82.52920651436,
       49.428099941567 
    ] 
  },
   "properties": {
     "icon": "bar-15",
     "title": "Bar",
     "description": "A Bar",
     "date": ISODate("2017-01-20T00:41:52.830Z") 
  },
   "__v": NumberInt(0) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

I C+P'd the code from another part of my code and failed to noice that I hadn't updated the following line:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
```

to:

```
Object.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$set` to update non root fields

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: id
}, {
  $set: {
    geometry: {
      type: object.geometry.type,
      coordinates: object.geometry.coordinates
    },
    properties: {
      icon: object.properties.icon,
      title: object.properties.title,
      description: object.properties.description
    }
  }
}, {
  new: true
}, (err, doc) => {
  console.log('err', err);
  console.log('doc', doc);
});
```